# renderizar datos laravel 9 con vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, frontend

Estoy tratando de crear un tabla dinámica con laravel 9 y vuejs 3, pero cuando creo todo mi componente e intento hacer un v-for de mi array de datos, este no pinta nada. He hecho un console log en mi método dentro de `onMounted()` y me muestra el objeto con su `value` correctamente. Cuando hago `{{ miArray }}` me pinta `[]` creo que por esta razon, no me está mostrando los datos que debe, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal. adjunto mi código del componente y los resultados en mi console:

```
<template>
    <div class="tabla offset-md-1">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th v-for="column in columns">
                    {{ column.label }}
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr v-for="data in treatmentData">
                    <td>{{ data.value.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.treatment_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.company_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.session_price }}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="alert alert-success d-none" role="alert" id="correcto"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert" id="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>prueba</h3>
        {{ treatmentData.value }}
        <div v-for="data in treatmentData">
            <p>{{ data.value }}</p>
            <p>{{ data.treatment_name }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

    export default {
        name: 'TreatmentIndex',

        setup () {
            const treatmentData = []
            const searchTerm = ref('')

            const columns = [
                {
                    label: 'ID',
                    field: 'id',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Name',
                    field: 'treatment_name',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Price',
                    field: 'session_price',
                },
            
                {
                    label: 'Edit',
                    field: 'edit'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Remove',
                    field: 'remove'
                },
            ]

            const getRecords = () => axios.get('/treatmentCompany/getAllTreatmentCompany')

            const remove = (event) => {
                if(confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){
                    axios.post('/treatmentCompany/treatment/'+event, {_method: 'DELETE'})
                    .then((response) => {
                        window.location.reload()
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }

            onMounted(() => {
                getRecords()
                    .then((response) => {
                        treatmentData.value = response.data

                        console.log(treatmentData)
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
                })

            return {
                treatmentData,
                remove,
                columns,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

La tabla me la crea, pero esta vacía.

**UPDATE**

He modificado mi componente en la funcion onMounted ya que antes usaba una variable para almacenar la función. He creado ahora la llamada asincrona dentro de esta función y con await. Pero obtengo el mismo resultado:

```
<script>
    import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
    export default {
        name: 'TreatmentIndex',
        setup () {
            const treatmentData = ref([])
            const searchTerm = ref('')
            const columns = [
                {
                    label: 'ID',
                    field: 'id',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Name',
                    field: 'treatment_name',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Price',
                    field: 'session_price',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Edit',
                    field: 'edit'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Remove',
                    field: 'remove'
                },
            ]
            
            const remove = (event) => {
                if(confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){
                    axios.post('/treatmentCompany/treatment/'+event, {_method: 'DELETE'})
                    .then((response) => {
                        window.location.reload()
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }
            onMounted(async () => {
                const res = await axios.get('/treatmentCompany/getAllTreatmentCompany')
                treatmentData.value = res.data.treatment.data;
                console.log(treatmentData.value);
            });
            
            return {
                treatmentData,
                remove,
                columns,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

el resultado de la ejecución sigue siendo la tabla vacía pero en el console tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**UPDATE 2**

```
<script>
    import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
    const treatmentData = ref([])
    const searchTerm = ref('')
    export default {
        setup () {

            const remove = (event) => {
                if(confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){
                    axios.post('/treatmentCompany/treatment/'+event, {_method: 'DELETE'})
                    .then((response) => {
                        window.location.reload()
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }

            onMounted(async () => { const { data } = await axios.get('/treatmentCompany/getAllTreatmentCompany')
                    treatmentData.value = data.treatment.data;
                    console.log(treatmentData.value);
            })

            return {
                treatmentData,
                remove,
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

este script el resultado en el console es la imagen adjunta en la pregunta, pero en el template al hacer el v-for no puedo extraer los datos.

Gracias por leerme y la ayuda

Comment: El problema cero radica en tu función `getRecords ` intenta hacer asíncrona

Comment: @Jozaguts mismo resultado: lo he hecho así:

import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'


const datatablePhysios = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
    import('./components/datatablePhysios.vue')
)

Comment: Dentro del template no debes de hacer uso del .value    `{{ treatmentData}} ` con eso basta
`{{ treatmentData.value }}`
` <p>{{ data.value }}</p>  // value es un key de tus datos ?`

Comment: @Jozaguts he probado solo a poner {{ treatmentData }} y sigue saliendo un array vacio [] value, debería de llevar los datos. Todos los ejemplos de vue 3 he visto que se usa el composition API y es lo que intento implementar. Con data.value me devuelve el objeto proxy y no se acceder a los datos que necesito ya que llevo muy poco con vue 3 ha cambiado tantisimo que he tenido que empezar de 0

Comment: Acabo de "replicar" tu ejemplo de esta manera

`<template>
     {{treatmentData }}
</temaplate>

<script>
 const treatmentData = ref([])
 onMounted(async () => { const { data } = await 
 axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')

      treatmentData.value = data
      // console.log(treatmentData.value);
    });
</script>`

funciona bien, el resultado se muestra en pantalla y en consola, @jozaguts contáctame y lo revisamos juntos

Comment: @Jozaguts gracias por tus respuestas y ayuda. No consigo extraer los datos del objeto proxy. He actualizado mi pregunta con mi script actualizado con tu respuesta y sigue apareciendo en el console Proxy{0: handler, Target y en target el indice 0 que contiene mi objeto del controller} tal y como puse en la foto de mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes intentar establecer un key-value en el bucle de Vue y especificar cual es la clave:

```
v-for='(item, index) in treatmentData' :key='index'
```

Y luego acceder:

```
item.id
item.treatment_name
item.company_id
item.session_price
```

Una captura de pantalla del valor de `treatmentData` (la del método `mounted`) puede ser de más ayuda

Saludos